# Mysql - Dynamically change column names by referencing another dataset

Tags: mysql, pivot, amazon-redshift

I have two MySQL tables and I need to dynamically rename the columns of one table, using the row values in the other table. 
For example:

**Table_1:**

```
Advertiser_ID, Ad_Id, Clicks, conv_342, conv_439
----------------------------------------------------------------------
23232         231112   5      10        12
23232         231119   22     34        19
```

**Table_2:**

```
conversion_id, conversion_name
-------------------------------
conv_342       Conversion_A
conv_439       Conversion_B
```

I need to map the conversion ids (which are column headers in table 1 and row values in table 2) to the conversion name, which is table 2 values.

**The outcome should look like:**

```
Advertiser_ID, Ad_Id, Clicks, Conversion_A, Conversion_B
----------------------------------------------------------------------
23232         231112   5      10        12
23232         231119   22     34        19
```

The list of conversion ids and names are very long, and can change dynamically, so this pivot can't be hard-coded in. The dataset is also pretty large to begin with. I've looked all over to find the solution, but none of the other similar questions gave me an answer to this.

This is MySQL running directly on a MySQL engine, so no programming languages allowed (PHP, Python, R, etc).

**What I tried**

I'm able to find determine if a Table_1 column header matches a row in Table_2, using this code:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME as 'fb_columns'
  FROM information_schema.columns 
 Where table_name='table1'
   AND COLUMN_NAME 
    IN (
         SELECT conversion_id 
           From table2
       )
```

But I can't figure out how to then rename the column using the conversion_name. Any help or leads would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** Of note, if you know a way to do this using Amazon Redshift, I have the resources to switch it from MySQL to Redshift. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to run an alter table statement - I'm not sure about mysql but in Oracle you can use something like execute immediate and execute a statement that affects DDL / DML within a script that references a variables provided by a cursor - but that's a programming language so... ... ...

Comment: @Jeff I can run an alter table, but yeah I don't believe MySQL lets you do execute immediates...

Comment: An option may be to use a combination of [13.6.6 Cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) and [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out using MySQL. Here's the solution.

**STEP 1:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS renameCols;
```

**STEP 2:**

You need two tables: *original_cols* which should have a list of all columns which do NOT need renaming. (This query can be something like 
`select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = original_table_name`. For more details about that, check out [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html).

And then *joined_mapping* should have the columns which need re-naming, along with the new column name. For example, in the original question, that would be the code snip underneath the title *What I tried*.
(Make sure *joined_mapping* doesn't have NULLs.)

Then, here comes the real good part:

This procedure uses a [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to loop through all of the `cols` (columns which need to be renamed) and rename them with the Name column from the joined_mapping. Then it also includes all of the `original_cols` (columns which should not get renamed).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE renameCols ()
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_table;
SET session group_concat_max_len = 18446744073709551615;
SET @originals = NULL;
SET @cols = NULL;
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('`',col,'`')) INTO @originals FROM original_cols;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT ('`',original_column_name,'` as "Conversion: ',conversion_name,'"')) INTO @cols
FROM joined_mapping;

SET @sql = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE new_table AS select ", @originals, " 
                   , ", @cols ," from fb_direct");

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

**STEP 3:**

```
CALL renameCols()
```

**STEP 4:**

```
SELECT * FROM new_table
```